# background radial gradient is displaced in Firefox

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I have a dropdown menu where I separated the second-level menu items by a "fancy line" ( `<hr>` tag ). It's working in all browsers except Firefox, in which the separators are displaced outside the dropdown menu.

I've looked for coding errors everywhere but cannot seem to find any.

Can anybody help, please?

**My CSS code:**

```
hr.fancy-line {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
}

hr.fancy-line:before {
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 1em;
}

hr.fancy-line:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0.5em;
    top: 1px;
    background: initial;    
}

hr.fancy-line:before, 
hr.fancy-line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

hr.fancy-line, 
hr.fancy-line:before {  
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 75%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
}
```

Comment: what happen with my answer? It solves your problem, at least you can upvote or accept the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `position: relative` to the parent, because the `position: absolute` will be attached to the inmediate relative parent (if not, viewport):

https://jsfiddle.net/ks2gtpab/

```
hr.fancy-line {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    position:relative;
}
```

The other browsers seems to be wrong in behaviour, even if you think the bug is in firefox, it's because you set `top: 1px`, and this calculation will be made by the relative parent or viewport if there are not relative parent.